# NSTableView not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nstableview

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18319/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-23) instead of nib files, i used storyboarding. I have no idea what mistake i did. When i run it, its just showing the 10 tableview cells, it does not displaying the values that i passed.

This is the code i used ->

[image: this is the storyboard view]
     // MARK: - NSTableViewDataSource

```
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> NSView! {
        // 1
        var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableView.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView

        // 2
        if tableColumn.identifier == "BugColumn" {
            // 3

            cellView.imageView!.image = NSImage(named: "delete")!
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = "Alvin"
            return cellView
        }

        return cellView
    }



override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.tableView.setDataSource(self)
        self.tableView.setDelegate(self)
    }
```

Please help me to figure out, what i missing in here.? Output : i am just getting the default tableView cells ten times, there are values that i given in the dataSource. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag your question as iOS when your code is obviously for OSX (NSImage, NSTableView)?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Yeah, that i was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the tableView's identifier, but instead you should use the tableColumn's one:

```
var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableView.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^

var cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn.identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView
```